# No data in Stackdriver User defined monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to create a monitoring and alerting on stackdriver logging.
Expectation is that when an error is logged it is aggregated by the stackdriver monitoring every 15 mins and then alerts are triggered.

In the log viewer when I run following I can see the error in the logs.

```
resource.labels.job_name="test-01"
severity=(ERROR OR CRITICAL OR ALERT OR EMERGENCY)
```

[image]

There under `Actions` I click on `Create Matric`

This takes me to `Metric Editor` there I provide `Name` as `test-01` and `Type` as `Counter` and Click `Create Matric`

This takes me to `Logs-based Metrics` where under `User-defined Metrics` I see my matrix by the name `test-01`

From the options I click `View in Matrix Explorer` which takes me to `Metrics explorer` and I see following.

No matter what I do the graph never shows any data.

Any1 has any idea what is missing...

[image]

Comment: It seems that your metric shows when you have “ERROR OR CRITICAL OR ALERT OR EMERGENCY “, and your screenshot shows you choose 1 hour. Maybe you have not log on that hour. Did you try it with more time like 1W(1 week)?

Comment: While using the metrics explorer I realized that there's a delay on retrieving data, specially if it's the first time you're creating the chart

Comment: @AhmadP somehow it was not visible so I logged more errors and then I could see all of them but I am surprised that all the errors are not available in metrics may be something is wrong with aggregator

Comment: @manasouza yes that could be the issue but as I have mentioned in the above comment not each error in the stackdriver is visible in the metrics.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. 
Would you share the screenshots of your steps or documents that you follow?

You can review this google general document for [logs-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics)